# Shell script - List three columns with ECHO

Tags: shell, for-loop

Example:

```
$ cat 1.log 
1111 2222 3333
4444 5555 6666
7777 8888 9999
```

I need to add information in each column:

Example:

```
$ for i in $(cat 1.log | awk {'print $1'}) ; do echo "INFO: $i" ; done
INFO: 1111
INFO: 4444
INFO: 7777
```

Expected:

```
INFO: 1111 INFO1: 2222 INFO2: 3333
INFO: 4444 INFO1: 5555 INFO2: 6666
INFO: 7777 INFO1: 8888 INFO3: 9999
```

I would need the "echo"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`$ awk '{print"INFO:"$1" INFO1:"$2" INFO2:"$3}' 1.log`

Output:

```
INFO:1111 INFO1:2222 INFO2:3333
INFO:4444 INFO1:5555 INFO2:6666
INFO:7777 INFO1:8888 INFO2:9999
```